# Bucket permissions on Amazon

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to allow access to the bucket files to only users with signature on their URL (timestamp).

I added a policy to the the bucket:

```
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy1416760830285",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1416760822325",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "*"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*",
            "Condition": {
                "Null": {
                    "aws:TokenIssueTime": false
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

But still anyone can access my URL.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The fact that "anyone can still access" your objects suggests that you have granted default access to objects, and you are then trying to Deny access that does not have a signature (Pre-signed URL).

If you wish to only provide access to objects in Amazon S3 by using a Pre-Signed URL, then you do not require a Bucket Policy. To explain...

**By default, all objects in Amazon S3 are private.** You can then add permissions so that people can access your objects. This can be done via:

- Access Control List permissions on individual objects
- A Bucket Policy (as per yours above)
- IAM Users and Groups

A **[Pre-Signed URL](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURLJavaSDK.html)** can be used to grant access to S3 objects as a way of "overriding" access controls. A normally private object can be accessed via a URL by appending an expiry time and signature. This is a great way to serve private content without requiring a web server.

If your goal is to serve content only where a Pre-Signed URL is used, then:

- Do not assign any permissions via the normal methods listed above (this keeps them private by default)
- Use Pre-Signed URLs to access objects

This way, the only way to access an object will be to use a Pre-signed URL (which has a signature). No bucket policy is required.

Comment: thank you John.
My problem was that the objects in the bucket were shared.
I disabled the sharing and now access is allow only with Pre-Signed URLs.